# Можно ли обработать исключение красивее?

Tags: java, java-9

Решая простенькую задачу натолкнулся на ситуацию, в которой метод вызывает исключение, а мне надо его обработать.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            String time = "10:15:30 PM";
            String result = null;
            try {
                result = timeFormation(time);
            }
            catch(ParseException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(result != null && !result.equals(""))
                System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
        }

static String timeFormation(String time) throws ParseException {

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        SimpleDateFormat parseFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
        Date date = parseFormatter.parse(time);
        return dateFormatter.format(date);

        }
```

Я в исключениях не особо силен, поэтому не знаю, можно ли это сделать более красиво? Меня смущает именно то, что нам приходится создавать новый объект `String = null` из-за `try-catch`, а потом еще и устраивать ему тотальную проверку. Так и надо или есть способы лучше? И, пользуясь случаем, задам вопрос: правильно ли в методах при помощи `throws` сигнализировать о возможных исключениях или лучше сразу же в методе их и обработать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        try {
            String result = timeFormation(time);
            System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
        } catch(ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Хмм, это может стать решением, но только если в блоке `try` будет мало кода, как в моем примере. А что если например нам после получения этой переменной надо будет написать еще довольно много кода, использую эту переменную. Неужели придется все это в одном блоке `try` писать?

Comment: @NarasuOo Тогда много кода надо завернуть в отдельную функцию и вызывать ее внутри `try`, передавая туда `result`.

Comment: а вот это уже хорошее решение

Answer (score 0):

Если вы боитесь использования большого количества `catch`, то можно использовать класс более высокого уровня (грубо говоря, например, `Exception` (лучше, конечно, так не делать, но все же)) или `multi-catch` начиная с Java 7

А если вас смущает, что в блоке `try` очень много кода, то разделите его на отдельные функции, при том некоторые исключения можно обрабатывать там же.

Лично я считаю, что к этому нужно привыкнуть. Обобщая, можно сказать, что это особенность Java :). Например, те же геттеры и сеттеры (Boilerplate code), если не считать lombok. Java - это старый язык, который должен поддерживать миграционную совместимость.

Также можете посмотреть [Best Practice](https://stackify.com/best-practices-exceptions-java/) по использованию `try-catch`